# How to create a Ubuntu wiki page?

Tags: ubuntu-wiki, uds

I'm currently writing a blueprint for the trusty vUDS (first UDS for me) and there is in Launchpad the optional field to link to an Ubuntu Wiki page for longer specification, but seriously - it's not the first time.

I can't figure out how to create a new wiki page. I don't even know how to navigate the wiki, there is no visual indicator or button I could press.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to wiki.ubuntu.com and then just add the title of what you want the page to be, like this:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MakeSomethingUp

Since the page doesn't exist click the link for "Create new empty page"

Comment: Thanks a lot. An easy solution but not really intuitive. The next question is how to find other peoples wiki pages. Just searching the void seems to me pretty cumbersome.

Comment: Searching the void is the only way unfortunately.